# How to copy the latest file from Sharepoint to Blob Storage using Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to extract the latest excel file from Sharepoint into Azure blob storage using Logic App.

I created the flow and it's working. However, it's copying all the files from the sharepoint to Blob.

Below is my flow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUISA.png)

I get new excel file everyday in my Sharepoint (/Shared documents/Data), hence I used list folder to locate it.

Then I used Filter array to filter the files as last modified with less than or equal to 5 m

I don't get any error. However, it's copying all the files rather than last modified file.

Can anyone advise how to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the trigger specific to 'When new file is added in sharepoint folder'. Documentation link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepoint/#when-a-file-is-created-in-a-folder